# How to phrase the following sentence in a cover letter

Tags: phrase-requests

I cannot come across proper syntax to pitch the following sentence. I will really appreciate any help.

"During the same year, I led career guidance visit the XXX as IEEE president and ABC University's representative"

The sentence above is the actual sentence what I have written in the cover letter. But as one comment mention that this sentence does not make any sense. I want to say the following

"During the same year (in which I did some other activities mentioned in previous sentence), I led a group of students to a XXX industry for the purpose of career guidance so they have the opportunity to learn more about after-graduation careers. My role was IEEE president + I was representing my university as well"

Comment: As it stands, this sentence makes no sense, so it's impossible to tell what you mean.

Comment: oops my bad. I have added more details now.

Comment: It could be *As IEEE president for(using for because I assumed that you are not James A. Jefferies) ABC University, I led a(delete the a if there were many visits) career visit(add s if there were many visits) to XXX, during the same year.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without more context (is IEEE an organization at the university? what does it mean that they visited an industry? was it a trip to one company or multiple companies in the industry? what does leading the visit involve? why is this event relevant to the job?), but here's my shot:

"During the same year, I represented ABC university as IEEE president by leading a group of students on a visit to explore post-graduate career options within the XXX industry."

I would then follow it up with more details to explain the importance of your role in these visits/why it is relevant to the job you are applying for.